# Pagination with meteor and iron router not re-rendering

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I'm really struggling to understand what's going on here. I have a template

```
<template name="gallery">
  <div>
    <a href="/">1</a><a href="/gallery/2">2</a><a href="/gallery/3">3</a>
  </div>
  {{#each art}}
    {{name}} 
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

Then I have routes like this

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('/', {
    template: 'gallery',
    data: function() {
      var page = 1;
      return {
        page: page,
      };
    },
  });
  this.route('/gallery/:_page', {
    template: 'gallery',
    data: function() {
      var page = parseInt(this.params._page);
      return {
        page: page,
      };
    },
  });
});
```

Following [this article](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/template-level-subscriptions/) I'm using template subscriptions like this

```
  var G_PAGE_SIZE = 10;

  Template.gallery.onCreated(function() {
    var instance = this;
    var route = Router.current();
    instance.loaded  = new ReactiveVar(0);

    instance.autorun(function() {
      var pageId = parseInt(route.params._page);
      var page = pageId - 1;
      var skip = page * G_PAGE_SIZE;

      var subscription = instance.subscribe('artForGrid', skip, G_PAGE_SIZE);
      if (subscription.ready()) {
        instance.loaded.set(1);
      }
    });

    instance.art = function() {
      return Art.find({});
    };
  });

  Template.gallery.helpers({
    art: function() {
      return Template.instance().art();
    },
  });
```

It works but when I click one of the links changing the route the page doesn't re-render

So ... [some other answer on here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30158273/128511) said that's because there's no reactive connection between data changing on the route through the router and the template.

So I tried use `route.state` which as a ReactiveDict (not sure where that came from). If it's part of iron:router or if it's part of reactive-var

Anyway I changed the code to

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('/', {
    template: 'gallery',
    data: function() {
      var page = 1;
      this.state.set('page', page);  // <------------ADDED
      return {
        page: page,
      };
    },
  });
  this.route('/gallery/:_page', {
    template: 'gallery',
    data: function() {
      var page = parseInt(this.params._page);
      this.state.set('page', page);  // <------------ADDED
      return {
        page: page,
      };
    },
  });
});
```

In the `onCreated`

```
  Template.gallery.onCreated(function() {
    var instance = this;
    var route = Router.current();
    instance.loaded  = new ReactiveVar(0);

    instance.autorun(function() {
      var pageId = route.state.get('page'); // <--------- CHANGED
      var page = pageId - 1;
      var skip = page * G_PAGE_SIZE;

      var subscription = instance.subscribe('artForGrid', skip, G_PAGE_SIZE);
      if (subscription.ready()) {
        instance.loaded.set(1);
      }
    });

    instance.art = function() {
      return Art.find({});
    };
  });

  Template.gallery.helpers({
    art: function() {
      return Template.instance().art();
    },
  });
```

That doesn't work either except sometimes. In the interest of debugging I added a `console.log` to the route

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('/', {
    template: 'gallery',
    data: function() {
      var page = 1;
      this.state.set('page', page);
      console.log("/root");  // <------------ADDED
      return {
        page: page,
      };
    },
  });
  this.route('/gallery/:_page', {
    template: 'gallery',
    data: function() {
      var page = parseInt(this.params._page);
      this.state.set('page', page);
      console.log("/gallery/" + page);  // <------------ADDED
      return {
        page: page,
      };
    },
  });
});
```

Suddenly it starts working !???!@!?   I remove the console.logs and it stops

I also tried adding actions without the console.logs

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('/', {
    template: 'gallery',
    data: function() {
      var page = 1;
      this.state.set('page', page);
      return {
        page: page,
      };
    },
    action: function() {              // <- added
      var page = 1;                   // <- added
      this.state.set('page', page);   // <- added
      this.render();                  // <- added
    },                                // <- added
  });
  this.route('/gallery/:_page', {
    template: 'gallery',
    data: function() {
      var page = parseInt(this.params._page);
      this.state.set('page', page);
      return {
        page: page,
      };
    },
    action: function() {                      // <- added
      var page = parseInt(this.params._page); // <- added
      this.state.set('page', page);           // <- added
      this.render();                          // <- added
    },                                        // <- added
  });
});
```

That doesn't work either.

---

## update

So using `Router.current().data().???` seems to make it work. It's now this

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('/', {
    template: 'gallery',
    data: function() {
      var page = 1;
          // <--- removed this.state() stuff
      return {
        page: page,
      };
    },
         // <---- removed action stuff
  });
  this.route('/gallery/:_page', {
    template: 'gallery',
    data: function() {
      var page = parseInt(this.params._page);
          // <--- removed this.state() stuff
      return {
        page: page,
      };
    },
         // <---- removed action stuff
  });
});
```

helper

```
  Template.gallery.onCreated(function() {
    var instance = this;
    instance.loaded  = new ReactiveVar(0);

    instance.autorun(function() {
      var route = Router.current();    // <----- Moved from 3 lines up
      var pageId = route.data().page;  // <--------- CHANGED
      var page = pageId - 1;
      var skip = page * G_PAGE_SIZE;

      var subscription = instance.subscribe('artForGrid', skip, G_PAGE_SIZE);
      if (subscription.ready()) {
        instance.loaded.set(1);
      }
    });

    instance.art = function() {
      return Art.find({});
    };
  });

  Template.gallery.helpers({
    art: function() {
      return Template.instance().art();
    },
  });
```

No idea if this is now *correct* or if I'm just getting lucky like with the console.log editions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that your `autorun` function is not being re-run because you are not using any reactive variables. I'm not sure if `Router.current()` or `Router.current().data()` are reactive, but if they're not, then this explains the issue clearly for me. To test this, try putting some console logging in your `autorun` function.

Now, I would proposed some revisions that may work for you.

**Routing code**

Redirect to `'/'` URL to `'/gallery/1'` so you can re-use routing code

```
Router.route('/', function(){
    this.redirect('/gallery/1');
});
```

Sending the page number in the data object to your template is important so that we can use this object in our `autorun` function

```
Router.route('/gallery/:_page', {
    template: 'gallery',
    data: function() {
        return {
            page: this.params._page,
        };
    }
});
```

*Also, you don't need to use `parseInt` method unless you are trying to re-route or handle that exception in your routing code.*

**Gallery `onCreated` and `helpers`**

There is a `Template.subscriptionsReady` helper provided by Meteor so you don't have to manually check if the subscription is loaded unless you really want it. Here's the [Template.subscriptionsReady documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/Blaze-TemplateInstance-subscribe)

Here's a simplified version of your `onCreated` method using the `template.data` object which was built by the routing code above. Using the `autorun` wrapper is important so that it will re-run when `template.data` is changed by your router.

```
var G_PAGE_SIZE = 10;

Template.gallery.onCreated(function() {
    var instance = this;

    instance.autorun(function() {
        // access the data object built by your route code
        var pageId = instance.data.page;  

        var page = pageId - 1;
        var skip = page * G_PAGE_SIZE;

        instance.subscribe('artForGrid', skip, G_PAGE_SIZE);
    });

});
```

Define access to your reactive data sources using the `template.helpers` method.

```
Template.gallery.helpers({
    art: function() {
        return Art.find({});
    }
});
```

*Note: Not necessary to define your helper in the `onCreated` and  `template.helpers`*

Comment: Thank you for the detailed suggestions. They were super helpful

Comment: instance.data is not reactive, your code don"t work.
change with Router.current().data()